# Request permission for cross-domain request dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xss

Is it possible to make a cross-domain request from a Chrome extension without statically listing the domain in `manifest.json` (presumably by dynamically prompting the visitor for permission)?

For a use case, suppose I wanted to let visitors supply an RSS feed address, which I'd then query as part of my application's dashboard screen. I cannot list that domain in `manifest.json` since I clearly can't know the domain until the visitor enters it at runtime.

I'm hoping there's some mechanism for dynamically requesting access to a domain ("This extension wants to browse your data on www.example.com; do you want to allow this?")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to specify a [match pattern](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html) of: `http://*/*`